# Sitecore throw exception when index Date field

Tags: solr, indexing

We are seeing the error below being thrown in our production environment. In our QA and dev environments we don't see the error.

We have tried the following:

- Deleting the Solr index and rebuilding
- Copying the items that are causing and error and testing them locally. They index locally without and error.
- Our QA environment works and this is pointed at Solr 8.1.1, the same as prod. So we don't think it is a Solr issue.

Sitecore version: 9.3

Solr: 8.1.1

The only difference we can see is that Dev is XP0 and Prod is XP1 scaled.

```
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=sitecore://books/{17e9406e-ed4b-4148-b99f-c9f102924b35}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=books_index] Error adding field 'published_tdt'='false' msg=Invalid Date String:'false'</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Do you know what is causing this error?

Comment: can you check the format of the string date you pass to solr: is it this format : YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ ?

Comment: for me looks like you send the value "false"

Comment: It seems you are using a custom index named "books_index". Could you please add the configuration details of this custom index?

Comment: It seems like the schema is different between the environments. Compare the schemas and verify that the dynamic date fields are configured properly in your Solr index (like `*_dt` etc.) IIRC there's also a missing piece in the default schema provided by Sitecore, where single dates are included but date collections are not mapped.